# Conexões e gerenciamento

Tags: php, pdo

<sub>**PHP - PDO, Conexões e gerenciamento de conexões**</sub>

> A conexão permanece ativa por toda a vida útil do objeto PDO. Para fechar a conexão, é preciso destruir o objeto, garantindo que todas as referências restantes para ele são excluídos - você faz isso através da atribuição de NULL para **a variável que contém o objeto**. Se você não fizer isso explicitamente, o PHP irá fechar automaticamente a conexão quando o script termina.

Pelo manual do PDO, basta atribuir NULL.

```
$database = new PDO( ... ) // instância
$database = null           // close
```

---

Minha dúvida apareceu quando li o singular: *`a variável que contém o objeto`*.
Veja o exemplo abaixo.

A instância do PDO está presente em `$pdo` e `Crud $pdo`.
Em casos como este, onde o objeto está em duas variáveis, ambas devem ser NULL?

```
$pdo = new PDO( ... )

class Crud
{
     function insert( $pdo, $argumentos )
     {
          $this-> pdo = $pdo;
     }
}
```

> **OBS**
>   <sub>1) Sei que é opcional pois o PHP faz isso no final como mostra a DOC</sub>
>
>   <sub>2) É um exemplo simples e ilustrativo, qualquer questão sobre PATTERN deve ser ignorada :)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, se mais de uma variável aponta para o mesmo objeto, todas precisam receber `null` para que a memória ocupada pelo objeto seja liberada.

O PHP mantém uma [contagem de referências](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) para os objetos. Quando o *garbage collector* roda, ele procura os objetos com zero referências, e libera a memória correspondente. Se houver uma ou mais referências a determinado objeto, ele é considerado "vivo" (em uso), e portanto a memória que ele ocupa não pode ser liberada.

Como os objetos do tipo PDO não possuem um método para fechar a conexão, ela só é encerrada quando o objeto é efetivamente destruído, por isso o procedimento descrito acima é necessário.

Comment: Vou ler o link de referencia. obrigado pela explicacao, nao conhecia esse procedimento do PHP para limpar a memoria.